# Extract cpio.gz with two archives inside

Tags: linux, unix, gzip, cpio

I've got cpio.gz created with command:
`cat a.cpio.gz b.cpio.gz > c.cpio.gz`

Now i want to extract this c.cpio.gz file to b.cpio.gz and a.cpio.gz. How can i achive that?

Comment: Well, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112604/find-gzip-start-and-end) and look for the start marker of `b.cpio.gz` in `c.cpio.gz` and extract files before and after that marker excluding and including where needed. Next time use `tar`.

Comment: Well i must use cpio.gz due to requirements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got 2 `.gz` files, `a.txt.gz`and `b.txt.gz`. Then:

```
$ cat a.txt.gz b.txt.gz > c.txt.gz
$ hexdump -C c.txt.gz
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 f7 a3 00 59  00 03 61 2e 74 78 74 00  |.......Y..a.txt.|
00000010  4b 2c 4e e1 4a 24 80 01  a9 66 ae 58 24 00 00 00  |K,N.J$...f.X$...|
00000020  1f 8b 08 08 01 a4 00 59  00 03 62 2e 74 78 74 00  |.......Y..b.txt.|
00000030  2b 2c 4f e5 2a 24 0a 73  a5 72 01 00 70 24 d5 0a  |+,O.*$.s.r..p$..|
00000040  2d 00 00 00                                       |-...|
```

See those `1f 8b 08` starting at 0x00 and 0x20, they are the BOF markers for `.gz` files ([based on the article I referred to in the OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632587/extract-cpio-gz-with-two-archives-inside#comment74313949_43632587)). Now some awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS="\x1f\x8b\x08"; ORS="" }  # set the marker to RS
NR==2 { print RS $0 > "a2.txt.gz" }  # output the marker and what's after first marker
NR==3 { print RS $0 > "b2.txt.gz" }  # output the marker and what's after the second
' c.txt.gz
```

Produces 2 files and based on my `diff` they are identical to original files.